LP relaxation of bounded knapsack problem with constraints on the item bounds
The LP relaxation of the bounded knapsack maximization problem with weights $w_i=1$ is
\begin{align}
&\underset{x}{\max} \sum_i c_i x_i \\
& st \sum_i x_i \leq W \\
& \forall i, 0\leq x_i \leq n_i
\end{align}
for which I know that the items should be picked by order of decreasing values of $c_i$.
I am facing a very similar problem which can be written as
\begin{align}
&\underset{x, p}{\max} \sum_i c_i x_i \\
& st \sum_i x_i \leq W \\
& \forall i, 0\leq x_i \leq p_i \\
& \lVert p-\hat{p}\rVert_1 \leq \delta
\end{align}
where $p$ and $\hat{p}$ are a probability distributions and $W\leq 1$.
Basically, we can optimize the quantity of each item, without deviating too much from a reference.
With the addition of the last line, I understand intuitively that the distribution $p$ should be chosen such that $p_i$ should be maximized by order of decreasing values of $c_i$.
If I try to optimize the dual instead:
the Lagrangian is
$$L(x,p,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\sum_i c_i x_i + \alpha (W-\sum_i x_i) + \sum_i \beta_i (p_i-x_i) + \gamma(\delta - \lVert p-\hat{p})\rVert_1)$$
The primal is $\underset{p, x\geq 0}{\max} \underset{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0}{\min} L(x, p, \alpha, \beta, \gamma)$.
The dual is $\underset{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0}{\min} \underset{p, x\geq 0}{\max} \sum_i x_i (c_i - \alpha - \beta_i) + \alpha W +  \sum_i \beta_ip_i + \gamma(\delta - \lVert p-\hat{p}\rVert)_1)$.
It can be written
\begin{align}
\underset{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0}{\min} \underset{p\geq 0}{\max} \quad&\alpha W +  \sum_i \beta_ip_i + \gamma(\delta - \lVert p-\hat{p}\rVert)_1)\\
&\text{st }c_i - \alpha - \beta_i \leq 0
\end{align}
Now I should get rid of the $p_i$ but I don't know how to handle the norm.
If I remove $\lVert p - \hat{p}\rVert_1\leq \delta$ and simply enforce that $p$ is a probability distribution, the problem becomes
\begin{align}
\underset{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0}{\min} \underset{p\geq 0}{\max}\quad & \alpha W +  \sum_i p_i\beta_i + \gamma(1-\sum_i p_i)\\
&\text{st }c_i - \alpha - \beta_i \leq 0
\end{align} which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
&\underset{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0}{\min}\quad  \alpha W +  \gamma\\
&\begin{aligned}\text{st }&c_i - \beta_i \leq \alpha\\ &\beta_i\leq \gamma\end{aligned}
\end{align}
And finally, it amounts to $\underset{\beta}{\min} \underset{I, x_i\neq 0}{\max}(c_i-\beta_i)W + \underset{I, p_i\neq 0}{\max} \beta_i$ because the constraint are inactive when $x_i=0$ or $p_i=0$.
Thus, the sum is minimized by having $x_i=p_i=0$ except for the least rewarding item. I definitely lost track somewhere, this is the opposite of the desired conclusion.

Do you require that $\sum_i p_i=1$ and $p_i \ge 0$?  Also, is $\hat{p}$ a probability distribution?

Yes indeed, both are probability distributions. I have updated my question.

We can take $p=\hat{p}$, and augment $p_1$ as much as possible (where object one has the highest cost) while decreasing $p$ for the lowest costs, so that we still get a probability distribution. The optimality can be proved by duality, or by writing the simplex tableau at optimality.

The norm can be linearized as $\sum_i y_i \le \delta$ with $-y_i \le p_i -\hat{p}_i \le y_i$.
